# NSMutableRequest not working for the second time (ARC enabled)

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlrequest, nsurlsession, nsmutableurlrequest

I am performing JSON POST request by clicking UIButton and after the submission, segue perform can be done. So, After submitting values, I cannot perform POST request anymore. It shows status code 200 and response is OK. But, data is not reflected in the Backend. Here is my code:

```
(IBAction)transitsurveydone:(id)sender {
    if([tempArray count]!=0){
       /* alert= [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Survey Submission"
                                          message:@"Please Enter your location"
                                         delegate:self
                                cancelButtonTitle:@"Modify"
                                otherButtonTitles:@"Submit",nil];
        alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
        alert.tag=2;
        [alert show];*/

        NSLog(@"Caption array is %@ %@",captionArray,tempArray);

        NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"myURL"]];

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

        NSMutableDictionary *postDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];


        NSMutableDictionary *d=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@10,@"\"Bus\"", nil];
            NSMutableArray *m=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        NSString *str1,*str2,*str3,*str4;
               // Checking the format






        if(tempArray.count==1){
            for (int x=0; x<1; x++) {
                str1=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\"%@\"",[captionArray objectAtIndex:x]];
                [d setObject:[tempArray objectAtIndex:x]  forKey:str1];


            }


        [request setHTTPBody:[[NSString stringWithFormat: @"{\n    \"instance\" : %@,\n    \"response_method\": \"web\",\n    \"routes\": [\n                {%@:%@}\n        ]\n}",randomString,str1,[d objectForKey:str1] ]dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        }
          NSLog(@"%@:%@",str1,[d objectForKey:str1]);        
        NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
        NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                                completionHandler:
                                      ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

                                          if (error) {
                                              // Handle error...
                                              return;
                                          }

                                          if ([response isKindOfClass:[NSHTTPURLResponse class]]) {
                                              NSLog(@"Response HTTP Status code: %ld\n", (long)[(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response statusCode]);
                                              NSLog(@"Response HTTP Headers:\n%@\n", [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response allHeaderFields]);
                                          }

                                          NSString* body = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                                          NSLog(@"Response Body:\n%@\n", body);
                                      }];
        [task resume];


        NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
        NSError *error = nil;


        NSData *respData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
        NSLog(@"~~~~~ Status code: %d", [response statusCode]);

        if([response statusCode]==200){
            UIAlertView  *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"Transit Survey submitted" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];
            alert.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation( 10, 740);
            [alert show];
            [self performSelector:@selector(dismissAlert:) withObject:alert afterDelay:1.0f];
            submitteddonthide=NO;
        }
        else{
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"Transit Survey Submission Failed" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];
        alert.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation( 10, 740);
        [alert show];
        [self performSelector:@selector(dismissAlert:) withObject:alert afterDelay:1.0f];
        }


        if([prefs integerForKey:@"humandone"]==1){
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"transittohuman" sender:nil];
        }
        else{
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"gobackfromtransit" sender:nil];
        }


    }
```

`

The above code is in IBAction

Comment: You might want to check what's happening on the backend.  Is it receiving the connection?  If it's returning 200, what's it doing with the data?

Comment: It contains data in alphanumeric format. But, Backend doesn't have saved data

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine and there is no any issues.
If this issue is happens all the time, add "Advanced Rest Client" add-on to chrome browser and test your server URL passing respective input values. If this process also can't be able to update values on your backend there should be some issue on your backend.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of thoughts:

1. You are using status code to determine whether the server inserted the data correctly or not. You should actually have your web service build an affirmative response (in JSON, would be great) that says whether data was successfully inserted or not. You should not be relying solely on the web server's request response code.
2. I would observe the request with something like [Charles](http://charlesproxy.com) and make sure it looks OK.
3. You're building a JSON request manually, which is very fragile. I would suggest using Charles to observe the request, and copy and paste it into http://jsonlint.com and make sure it's OK.
4. Even better, use `NSJSONSerialization` which is more robust and easier to use.
5. Also, you're sending this request twice. Lose this second request (you shouldn't do synchronous requests, anyway) and put all of your confirmation logic inside the session's completion handler block.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. After struggling a bit, Clearing cookies helped me a lot :-

Here is a chunk of code, which is pretty much simple

```
 NSHTTPCookieStorage *cookieStorage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
 NSArray *cookies = [cookieStorage cookiesForURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    for (NSHTTPCookie *cookie in cookies) {
        NSLog(@"Deleting cookie for domain: %@", [cookie domain]);
        [cookieStorage deleteCookie:cookie];
    }
```

Thank you Mr. reddys and Rob for the suggestions